# Is it possible to segregate results in PHP MySQL Query with LIMIT data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table with 3500 rows (actually there are lot more then that). I need to know if that's possible to fetch all and divide them in a set of 1000 each. I understand last set would be of 500 rows, but thats fine.

I need to perform an automated query to generate sitemap with 1000 entries at the max.

**UPDATE**

So I need 4 sets out of above query with 1000 entries in first 3 arrays and 500 entries in last array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it from the level of SQL query, you can use OFFSET which is available with LIMIT ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000
```

etc.

The shorter syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000, 0
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000, 1000
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 1000, 2000
```

But if you want to load all 3500 rows with a query, use `array_chunk()` ([LINK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)):

```
$allRows = [/* your data */];
$chunkSize = 1000;
$chunks = \array_chunk($allRows, $chunkSize);
```

Comment: Thannks. I have about over 12000 rows. Is there method so that I dont have to specify LIMIT 1000, 2000 and so on. Can it me automatic because sometimes I may not know the exact available number of rows. And is my approach correct?

Comment: I think not. First you'll need to load information about how many rows you have. For example, with separate query which uses `COUNT` clause and which will be executed before loading target data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`. Read the manual [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

If you want first 1000 rows use:

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

If you want other 1000 rows use:

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 1000, 1000
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT    0, 1000;
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000, 1000;
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2000, 1000;
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3000, 500;
```